# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, bulk-load

I was running hbase bulk load program in single node cluster on terminal. the hadoop command for ruuning this job

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH='hbase classpath' hadoop jar /home/cloudera/Videos/hbaseBulk.jar /user/cloudera/Game1.csv /user/cloudera/hbase NBAFinal2010
```

input path: `/user/cloudera/Game1.csv`

output path: `/user/cloudera/hbase`

hbase table name: `NBAFinal2010`

```
13/06/06 15:18:39 INFO mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat: Writing partition information to hdfs://localhost:8600/user/cloudera/partitions_1370512119021
    13/06/06 15:18:39 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    13/06/06 15:18:39 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: rsrc:zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.0.1.jar
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(TableMapReduceUtil.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(TableMapReduceUtil.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(HFileOutputFormat.java:341)
        at Driver.main(Driver.java:50)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: rsrc:zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.0.1.jar
        at java.net.URI.checkPath(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:154)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Can you show your 'hbase classpath'? You can not use relative paths.

Comment: /home/cloudera/Desktop/clouderaCDH4/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1/conf:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/lib/tools.jar:/home/cloudera/Desktop/clouderaCDH4/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1:/home/cloudera/Desktop/clouderaCDH4/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1-security.jar:/home/cloudera/Desktop/clouderaCDH4/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1-security-tests.jar:/home/cloudera/Desktop/clouderaCDH4/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/cloudera/Desktop/clouderaCDH4/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/cloudera/Desktop/clouderaCDH4/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1/lib/asm-3.2.jar:

Comment: there is no more space in comments fields

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If yes, please share the solution. Thanks